# AWS DataPipeline says DynamoDB Table not found

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

My pipeline is configured to copy data from S3 bucket to DynamoDB Table. I am using HiveActivity with the following script:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE s3_table (hash STRING, attribute STRING) LOCATION '#{myInputS3Loc}';
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE #{myDDBTableName} SELECT * FROM s3_table;
```

I am getting this error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 2:23 Table not found 'TableName'
```

I have verified that the table exists in DynamoDB. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

In your Data Pipeline, check the configuration for the DDB Table. Specifically check that the region is correct under Parameters of Configuration. I've seen it previously where it will default the region to us-east-1 whilst the intended target table was in a different region